# Using Fluster to cluster a list of firebase documents

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[I have a list of location documents in Firebase and Algolia that are displayed on my Flutter app's google map page as markers. There are over 50 location documents currently in my Firebase, but at a time only 20 markers are displayed on the map no matter what. There are no limitations set anywhere, but there is a maximum of 20 markers. In order for there to be more than 20 markers, I need to implement clusters in my map page but I am not able to. With this code being the code for my map page, how would I implement clusters?

```
import '../auth/auth_util.dart';
import '../backend/backend.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_ad_banner.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_google_map.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class FindCourtWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FindCourtWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.searchTerm,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String? searchTerm;

  @override
  _FindCourtWidgetState createState() => _FindCourtWidgetState();
}

class _FindCourtWidgetState extends State<FindCourtWidget> {
  LatLng? currentUserLocationValue;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  LatLng? googleMapsCenter;
  final googleMapsController = Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // On page load action.
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      currentUserLocationValue =
          await getCurrentUserLocation(defaultLocation: LatLng(0.0, 0.0));

      final usersUpdateData = createUsersRecordData(
        latLngLocation: currentUserLocationValue,
      );
      await currentUserReference!.update(usersUpdateData);
    });

    getCurrentUserLocation(defaultLocation: LatLng(0.0, 0.0), cached: true)
        .then((loc) => setState(() => currentUserLocationValue = loc));
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (currentUserLocationValue == null) {
      return Container(
        color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
              color: Color(0xFFF25454),
              size: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return FutureBuilder<List<CourtsRecord>>(
      future: CourtsRecord.search(
        term: '*',
        location: getCurrentUserLocation(
            defaultLocation: LatLng(37.4298229, -122.1735655)),
      ),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                color: Color(0xFFF25454),
                size: 50,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        List<CourtsRecord> findCourtCourtsRecordList = snapshot.data!;
        return Title(
            title: 'findCourt',
            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Scaffold(
              key: scaffoldKey,
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              body: Stack(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                            child: FlutterFlowGoogleMap(
                              controller: googleMapsController,
                              onCameraIdle: (latLng) =>
                                  setState(() => googleMapsCenter = latLng),
                              initialLocation: googleMapsCenter ??=
                                  currentUserLocationValue!,
                              markers: findCourtCourtsRecordList
                                  .map(
                                    (findCourtCourtsRecord) =>
                                        FlutterFlowMarker(
                                      findCourtCourtsRecord.reference.path,
                                      findCourtCourtsRecord.location!,
                                      () async {
                                        context.pushNamed(
                                          'courtDetailsCopy',
                                          params: {
                                            'court2': serializeParam(
                                              findCourtCourtsRecord,
                                              ParamType.Document,
                                            ),
                                          }.withoutNulls,
                                          extra: <String, dynamic>{
                                            'court2': findCourtCourtsRecord,
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  .toList(),
                              markerColor: GoogleMarkerColor.red,
                              mapType: MapType.normal,
                              style: GoogleMapStyle.standard,
                              initialZoom: 14,
                              allowInteraction: true,
                              allowZoom: true,
                              showZoomControls: false,
                              showLocation: true,
                              showCompass: false,
                              showMapToolbar: false,
                              showTraffic: false,
                              centerMapOnMarkerTap: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0.8),
                        child: FFButtonWidget(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            context.pushNamed(
                              'addCourt',
                              extra: <String, dynamic>{
                                kTransitionInfoKey: TransitionInfo(
                                  hasTransition: true,
                                  transitionType:
                                      PageTransitionType.bottomToTop,
                                ),
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          text: 'Create Location',
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.add_circle,
                            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).white,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          options: FFButtonOptions(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 60,
                            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            textStyle:
                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).subtitle2.override(
                                      fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                                      color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).white,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-1, -1),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: 262,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).white,
                                Color(0x00FFFFFF)
                              ],
                              stops: [0, 1],
                              begin: AlignmentDirectional(0, -1),
                              end: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                        30, 30, 30, 0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional(
                                              -0.68, -0.75),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Hello ',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                            style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                .title2
                                                .override(
                                                  fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                                                  fontSize: 30,
                                                ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Align(
                                          alignment:
                                              AlignmentDirectional(0.63, -0.75),
                                          child: AuthUserStreamWidget(
                                            builder: (context) => Text(
                                              currentUserDisplayName
                                                  .maybeHandleOverflow(
                                                maxChars: 13,
                                                replacement: '…',
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .title2
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                                                        fontSize: 30,
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  children: [
                                    Align(
                                      alignment:
                                          AlignmentDirectional(-0.05, -0.85),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Find a great sport near you in 2 minutes',
                                        style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                            .bodyText1
                                            .override(
                                              fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                                              color: Color(0xFF504848),
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                            ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Align(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
                                      child: FlutterFlowAdBanner(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                        height: 50,
                                        showsTestAd: true,
                                        iOSAdUnitID:
                                            'ca-app-pub-4806655917667448/9288549735',
                                        androidAdUnitID:
                                            'ca-app-pub-4806655917667448/4144034269',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried using the Fluster package to implement clusters but my current knowledge in flutter/dart is not allowing me to go further in my implementation.